# What is '_' in Nginx listen option?

Tags: nginx-config

What is _ in nginx listen option?
I read `listen 80 _;` in nginx cookbook.
I found `server_name _;` mean just invalid server_name.
Then what is in listen?

ref https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server

Answer (score 0):

listen 443 ssl : makes nginx listen on all ipv4 address on the server, on port 443 (0.0.0.0:443)

while

listen [::]:443 ssl : makes nginx listen on all ipv6 address on the server, on port 443 (:::443)

[::]:443 will not make nginx respond on ipv4 by default, unless you specify parameter ipv6only=off :

listen [::]:443 ipv6only=off;

ssl :

```
The ssl parameter (0.7.14) allows specifying that all connections accepted on this port should work in SSL mode.
```

http2 :

```
The http2 parameter (1.9.5) configures the port to accept HTTP/2 connections.
```

This doesn't mean it accepts only HTTP/2 connections.

Comment: I mean, what does '_' flag mean in listen line. listen IP4 80 port and '_' mean what